# Correct way to reference project in different Git repository

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2022

I have a repository in Azure DevOps which hosts a solution/project providing common library code for our environment and is worked on by one team (and me).

A few other repositories in the same project are applications that require the use of this common library. I have both repositories setup in VS22 and can use the repository switcher to quickly switch between the 2 solutions to edit/compile them - essentially working on them both at the same time.

Currently, in the application project, I reference the common library by browsing to it's debug binary path and selecting the dll, but this means when I build the application in release, it still pulls in the common libraries debug dll.

Is there a more elegant way to reference this other project from a different repository like you would if both projects were in the same solution, so it uses the appropriate dll?

Comment: It looks like I can set the reference to not do a local copy and then use a post build event to copy the configuration specific version of the dll into the bin folder as one option

Comment: Publish the shared library as a common package and use a package manager in conjunction with Azure Artifacts to restore the dependency at compilation time.